# didUpdateLocations not being called when app is in background

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

didUpdateLocations is working fine when app is active and running in foreground, but it stops to work as soon as app enters into background

In .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *customerLocationManager;
```

in .m file

```
@synthesize customerLocationManager;



customerLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
customerLocationManager.delegate = self;
customerLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
customerLocationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;

if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
    [customerLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
[customerLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

I have integrated **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription** in info.plist. Background modes have been enabled and **Location Updates** option has been selected

Comment: Your CLLocationManager is a local variable. Big mistake. It should be some sort of persistent object, e.g. an instance variable / property.

Comment: @matt I've declared CLLocation manager as property, but the problem still persists

Comment: The code you posted uses a local variable to save the location manager. If this not your actual code then show your actual code.

Comment: @DuncanC , please see the edited actual code

Comment: Got the solution, I was not using allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> I have integrated NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in info.plist. Background modes have been enabled and Location Updates option has been selected

Good, but in iOS 9 there's a further requirement: you have to set the location manager's `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` to YES. You are not doing that, so you're not going to get background location updates.

Comment: @matt, This works for about 10 mins and stop updating, any idea why? It starts again if i bring the app to foreground.

Comment: @Prasad "This works for about 10 mins and stop updating, any idea why?" then you have not correctly configured the app to run in the background.

Comment: @matt, Yes i believe i did. I have added both NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and UIBackgroundModes in the plist, and initialized the LocationManager and set allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates to YES then started location updating. Above code is identical to mine.

Comment: And does your app obtain background location authorization?

Comment: Yes it does. I call requestAlwaysAuthorization method to request that, and i allow it when prompted. And it listed under Location Services in the Settings app as "Always".

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. Having little issue that when we kill the app by removing from app switcher, then it stops calling locationUpdates. Any solution to this?

Comment: Great, thanks. I'm wondering where I had to find it in Official Guides? Searching through guides only gives me CLLocationManager's API documentation.

Comment: of course, the key to allowing background location update is left out from the documentation...